# Single code base for multiple versions of single site

Tags: php, mysql, database, .htaccess, templates

I hope I've titled this question correctly, Ill try and explain what it is we are trying to achieve.

We have built a white label web app using a template of files and directories.

We are licensing this site to customers who can have their logo and custom colour styling via CSS on their version of the system. The site works exactly the same way for every customer.

Each site/customer has their own database and php configuration file to determine their database name and minor bits of information (address, contact info etc).

We have around 12 customers already but the problem we are finding is that we have to duplicate all our files and directories for each customer - making it very difficult when making small updates, we have to upload the new site 12 times.

To add another spanner in the works we set each customer up with their own URL and direct them to our their directory using htaccess.

So... Is there a way to use one version of the web app files and directories for all 12 customers, but if they go to www.customer1.com we can load in one configuration.php file and logo/css and the same for www.customer2.com and so on?

They all use the same template files, but the URL determines which configuration file to load.

I'm sorry if this is unclear, if it is I'll try and elaborate further.

Thanks

Comment: Yes just check the if there is a config file for url and load it if there is else use a default one

Comment: Parse $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; to extract the subdomain or customer domain, and then select the appropriate config, stylesheets, subdirectories, etc

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible solutions.

**First solution:**

I would use a shared directory that all the sites use, and leave only a config file in every user folder.

Then, the deploy script for a new custom will create symlinks for everything except the custom files. You may need to refactor some of the code to do this without writing hundreds of symlinks in the deploy script.

**Pros:**

- Each user has a separate directory, with only the bits of code that are custom to the user
- Customizations per customer are easy, since you can just break the symlink, copy the code and modify it

**Cons:**

- Decentralized customization checks

---

**Second solution:**

Route all users to use the same codebase, and depending on the URL (for example `customer1.mysite.com`), set some config variable. Make your site load the whole user config based on that variable.

**Pros:**

- Little to no changes to existing codebase (depending on how the code is written)
- Centralized place for all customer customization checks.

**Cons:**

- Customized code for users will be difficult to write/maintain

**References:**

- [Symlinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)

Comment: Thanks Vlad, I'm going to do some testing with a few options and will come back to indicate our chosen answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example of how to get the URL the user requested in php on this site: http://www.phpro.org/examples/Get-Domain-Name-From-URL.html

```
<?php

function getDomain($url)
{
    if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED) === FALSE)
    {
        return false;
    }
    /*** get the url parts ***/
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    /*** return the host domain ***/
    return $parts['scheme'].'://'.$parts['host'];
}
?>
```

You can then check to see which site they have chosen like this:

```
<?php
    //this next line from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/php-get-the-full-url
    $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

    if (getDomain($url) = "customer1.com"){
        //Load config for customer 1
        //Perhaps also store this in some flag for loading custom css later.
    }
    if (getDomain($url) = "customer2.com"){
        //Load config for customer 2
        //etc...
    }

?>
```

There may be better ways however as this requires you add another if statement for each customer.

Comment: Thanks DanJab, I'm going to do some testing with a few options and will come back to indicate our chosen answer